How to do password-less sign-in and Sign-up through AWS Amplify for Flutter
I'm currently developing a Flutter app with AWS as the backend, using the Flutter AWS Amplify library. I'm facing challenges with the authentication process, which relies on a unique user ID(number only) and mobile number for OTP verification, eliminating the need for passwords.
However, I've struggled to find a way to create users in AWS Cognito with only a user ID, leading me to resort to using a hardcoded password for all users.
I have two questions:

Can we create users without passwords in AWS using Flutter Amplify?
Is it acceptable to use hardcoded passwords for all users internally?

Any documentation or references would be appreciated.
I have successfully created the authentication process with hard-coded passwords.
I am expecting the following.
Signup

⁠user enters a unique number
⁠⁠user enter any mobile number ⁠⁠
app validates mobile number using SMS OTP
⁠And, new user is registered on AWS cognito

Signin

⁠user enters the unique number
⁠⁠user enters the mobile number
⁠⁠AWS signin will be successful on correct entries of both the info


It is not recommended to use hardcoded passwords for obvious security reasons. Instead, you could use the following reference implementation for passwordless auth using Cognito:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cognito-passwordless-auth
